# How to improve this amplifier so I can get up to 5 Watt output in 8ohm load

Tags: amplifier, basic

This is Class A amplifier I trying to make up to 5 Watt output for 8 \$ \Omega \$ load.
  Is this amplifier circuit OK?t gives about 800 mW out on 8 \$ \Omega \$ load.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at this simply, you have a "Darlington" output stage and this inevitably "loses" about 1.4 volts when powering a load - basically, from a 12 V supply, you can't deliver a "high" voltage greater than maybe 10.6 volts. To avoid distortion maybe 10 V is the maximum.

So, 10 V is the range of the signal that can be produced. In other words the output maximum level is ~10 Vp-p. This is the same as an RMS voltage of about 3.54 volts. If this feeds an 8 ohm load then the power delivered is about 1.56 watts.

That's the limit from 12 V I'm sorry to say. If you want to know why your amplifier only gives 0.8 watts you have to tell me more about the bias points in the circuit and how much distortion you are tolerating when 0.8 watts is being produced.

Clearly you could produce an output that is a square wave of 10.6 Vp-p and, into 8 ohms this is a power of about 3.5 watts but I suspect you are doing a sinewave measurement.

Comment: Hi andy aka  thanks Can I use push pull method for output stage with tip41 and 42 and how to use with less distortion.In this circuit Q1 is bias at VB/Ib is 983mV/44.34uA  and Vc/Ic is 8.06v/1.51mA with no input signals.

Comment: Push pull loses a 0.7 volts at the top power supply and 0.7 volts at the 0V end. This means no improvement. Maybe you should consider a bridge output driver - this effectively doubles the voltage that can be delivered to the speaker. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers

Comment: How to bias Q1 for maximum voltage gain and can i add one tip41 to output stage replies  R5 how to do that.

Comment: It's a class A amp - the output voltage needs to be nominally 6V minus half the volt drop lost across the transistor so maybe 5.3 volts. Set biasing for Q1 accordingly with R1 and R2. Regards adding a transistor, you are opening a can of works that deserves another question. This question has been "officially" answered as far as I can tell LOL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't.

You can't because the theoretical maximum you can get from a 12V powered single-ended amplifier is a 12V peak-peak sine, which is 6V/sqrt(2) = 4.25V RMS, which delivers (4.25)^2 / 8 = 2.25W into an 8 Ohm load. (This is a theoretical maximum, in practice it is considerably lower, because you will always have some voltage drop in your output stage.)

You shouldn't because the simple emitter-follower with a resistor load circuit you use is very ineffective, it will waste much more power in the load resistor than it delivers to the real load (the speaker). That is the reason you will only see it in low-power settings.

A realistic way to get 5W from 12V is to use a bridge amplifier (two output stages, one fed with the inverted signal), with push-pull (complimetary emitter follower) output stages. Next you'd have to worry about cross-over distortion, DC bias, feedback and stability. But unless you are in it for the learning process, you'd better buy one of the numerous chips that are used in car radio output stages. They cost next to nothing and are very easy to use.

A more modern approach would be to use a class-D amplifier, which is essentially a switching power supply acting as audio amplifier. You'd still need a bridge topology.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get 5w on 12V like Andy says.but you can do better by replacing R10 with a current sink maybe frying an egg at 1 amp.Your amp will now sound lovely .If you know what you are doing you can modulate the current source with the speaker return current which will allow you to halve the Idle current with no sonic penalty.Consider bootstraping your discrete darlington,or feed the driver from a higher rail like 15V if possible .Now you can expect a totaly normal output power considering 12V and 8 ohm.